# Average time on page includes the video view time in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase, brightcove

Google Analytics has one of the metric which is "average time on page", which is how long user stays on a certain page. I'm trying to figure out if someone watched the video on same page, would the time they viewed count towards this "average time on page" or not ?
FYI- Video is hosted on Brightcove and analytics information for page is extracted from Google Analytics.

Example :- The avg time spent on the landing page is ~2.5 minutes, which is very similar to the average ‘video seconds viewed’ (39010 seconds played / 290 views = 2.5 min per view on avg). We want to understand if people went to the site and only watched the video (if the video seconds played counts towards average time on page, then the answer is yes); or if people watched the video and spent an additional 2.5 minutes on the site which means 2.5 min +2.5 min = 5 min.

Google Analytics is implemented on Page only and in video we have video analytics.
Any link would be helpful ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you embed video on your page, then yes.

Comment: google analytics is not implemented in video, its only there in page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average time on a page is calculated from the difference between a hit sent to Google Analytics and the next hit sent.
**If you are not tracking the video** and a user lands in the page, watch the video and then exit, **you will not have average time** for that page.
Otherwise **if you are tracking the video** and for example sending an event to Analytics when the user has reached 25% of viewing it (non-interaction: false) the average time is calculated from the time difference between the event was sent to Analytics and when the user has landed on the page (and so on for the events of viewing 50%, 75%, 100%).

Tracking Brighcove Videos with Gooogle Analytics:
http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2016/03/tracking-brighcove-videos-with-gooogle-analytics.html

Comment: thank you @michele for the reply. I understood completely, let me take and exmaple to understand :- The avg time spent on the landing page is ~2.5 minutes, which is very similar to the average ‘video seconds viewed’ (39010 seconds played / 290 views = 2.5 min per view on avg). We want to understand if people went to the site and only watched the video (if the video seconds played counts towards average time on page, then the answer is yes); or if people watched the video and spent an additional 2.5 minutes on the site which means 2.5 min +2.5 min = 5 min.

Comment: if there are no interactions (pageviews or events) after the last interaction sent to Analytics, the extra seconds are not counted in the calculation of the average (for example if the user accesses the site and does nothing for 30 minutes or if the user browse the page but nothing is tracked except the pageview of the landing page and then he leaves the website or exceeds 30 minutes, the extra seconds are not counted in the calculation of the average).

You can't know if the user stay on the page for another 2.5 minutes if you do not send an hit to Analytics.